# Page appears after de registering from menu

Tags: menus, pages

I have created a menu and registered its location in functions.php

```
function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'footer-menu' => __( 'Footer Menu' )     
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

Then I added menu in footer.php

```
 <?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'footer-menu',
    'menu_class'     => 'footer-links-menu',
    ) );
?>
```

The menu appeared in menu section and worked perfectly displaying sample page, custom link and sample post.

[image]

[image]

Now I unchecked the menu in back end. (Footer Menu)

The custom link and sample post are not coming. But the sample page link appears. Can some one help me if I am missing anything as the whole menu should not appear.

Comment: It is a default behavior of wordpress nav menu. You can select Footer Menu but delete all item from it to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled by the `wp_nav_menu` argument `fallback_cb`, which is the `wp_page_menu` function by default. Set it to `false` to show nothing in the case a menu isn't assigned.

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'footer-menu',
    'menu_class'     => 'footer-links-menu',
    'fallback_cb'    => false,
) );
```